# What is "this" refer to in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I write a function to add listener to all elements match a specific selector, as below:

```
        //  Add event handler to all elements match a specific selector
        function addEventListenerToAll(selector, type, listener)
        {
            [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function(element) {
                if (element) {
                    element.addEventListener(type, listener);
                }
            });
        }
```

Then I invoke the function as below:

```
  addEventListenerToAll(".myclass", "click", function () {
      var url = this.getAttribute('myurl');  // What is 'this' refers to?
  });
```

Then what is 'this' in **this.getAttribute** refers to?

Based on my test, it refers to one of the elements in the foreach loop. However, I check this document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and it said in "Class context", 'this' in a non-static function refers to the current class object, otherwise, it defaults to the global object, in browser, it should be the **window** object.

So, as the listener function is not a class member function, it should refer to **window** instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can be given a different `this` scope to what would be the default. You can do this yourself with [the `apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). (Edit: as @pilchard pointed out below, this doesn't apply to arrow functions, which inherit the parent scope.) In event listeners, the `this` refers to the element the event listener was applied to (`currentTarget`).

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Comment: So long as the listener is passed a regular function and not an arrow function.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for this, forgot to mention it

Comment: It is covered in the link you provided, but so easily leads to confusion.